# VPython isn't Running with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vpython

When I try to run any `vpython` program on Visual Studio Code, it shows this error:

```
0:38: execution error: An error of type -10673 has occurred. (-10673)
69:77: execution error: Google Chrome got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)
70:78: execution error: Can’t get application "firefox". (-1728)
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51104)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 427, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 415, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vpython/no_notebook.py", line 150, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(fd.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 826, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Before it worked just fine with safari, and then I just suddenly got this error. I tried restarting Visual Studio Code and my Mac, but that didn't do any good either. How could I fix this problem and run my programs successfully on my computer?

Comment: Do you have Firefox installed? (Looking at the 3rd line of your error.) If not, that might be the problem (maybe you need to change some config to point to the browser you do have)

Comment: I use safari and google chrome

Comment: So you might need to look for a setting that tells your setup to use Firefox and change it to one of the two browsers you do have

Comment: But the second error was about Chrome `69:77: execution error: Google Chrome got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)`

Comment: Maybe it was waiting on Firefox and waited too long b/c Firefox wasn't found. At any rate, the Firefox issue is definitely there, but maybe there are other issues also

Comment: Another hypothesis would be that when it tried to launch it with `safari`, it didn't work, and it didn't work with `chrome` either, and then I also didn't have `firefox`, so the code didn't run, and the problem is that the browsers aren't running the code for some reason

Comment: It does say it's a broken pipe error, so I think Firefox was meant to be on one end of that pipe, which also make me think what I already said in the previous comment. Also, I don't see why it wouldn't work with Safari if it did try it first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241562/discussion-between-charlie-zhang-and-arseny).

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant, but the most recent version of vpython (about a week old)  uses WebGL 2 for the 3D rendering instead of the older WebGL 1, and old versions of Safari have WebGL 2 disabled. A friend told me that if you go to Safari, Preferences, Advanced, Enable Developer Menu, then go to Developer Menu and Select Experimental Features, you can enable WebGL 2. Also, it looks like you're using Python 3.10, which didn't support the vpython module until the recent update.